# How do you force Google Search App to keep Safe Search Filtering on

Tags: google-now, nexus-4, filter

My son just got a Nexus 4. I installed K9 Web Protection which does things like blocking other browsers, forces Safe Search to be on, but it also blocks Google Now by default. He really wants Google Now, but I do not want to allow Safe Search to be turned off.

At the moment, I see no way to keep Safe Search enabled on Google Now. Does anybody know how I can do this? Thanks.

Oh, this is on Nexus 4, Android 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

After quite a bit of searching and testing I don't think it's possible to do. Even locking SafeSearch on your Google account on the PC doesn't change it for the phone.

Regardless of this I would imagine that if your son can turn SafeSearch off even if you did lock it he would probably try getting around K9. This isn't too hard, there's even a suggested method in the product reviews, it apparently doesn't stop you from browsing within another app.

Comment: I didn't see anywhere in the reviews for a workaround. K9 actually redirects all other browsers to itself. Even Google Now actually opens it's links in the browser, however it is Google Images that I don't like.

Comment: @AceLegend 3rd review page in "Protection itself unmatched. Major gaps: app opens 15-25s after startup, enough to open a page in Chrome. My Avast antivirus can open right after start up. I open a video in MX Player, then later use "back", and protection is disabled. In-app browsers are not protected, eg Pocket. You can go to Wikipedia/Alexa, then anywhere."

Comment: I see. I know about In-App browsing, but I am not really worried about that. It is really just Google Images. And on the Nexus 4 performance is fine, although K9 search takes a while. Anyway, you don't happen to know of a third-party tool that can do something like blocking all pages even without the browser. I don't believe this is possible, as I doubt Google would allow it, but even one from the web would be okay. If not, I guess he's just out of luck.